# Converting Java LinkedHashMap to C++ std::map

Tags: java, c++, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to port a program from Java to C++ and I can't seem to figure out how to go about converting a LinkedHashMap into a std::map. I can't change the LinkedHashMap but I'm not restricted to std::map. I need it to produce the same key/value pair but ordering/hashing/whatever else doesn't really matter.

Java code to be converted:

```
List<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>(modelFull.faces.length);
Map<Point3D, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Point3D, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < modelFull.faces.length; i++) {
    Face f = new Face(modelFull.faces[i]);
    faces.add(f);
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        Point3D p = f.pts[k];
        Integer v = map.get(p);
        if (v == null) {
            v = 0;
        }
        map.put(p, v + 1);
    }
}
```

My attempt:

```
std::map<RVPoint3D, int> pointMap;
auto modelFaces = modelFull.getFaces();
for (const auto &face : modelFaces)
{
    Face newFace = Face(face);
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
    {
        RVPoint3D pt = newFace.getPts()[k];
        ++pointMap[pt];
    }
    faces.push_back(newFace);
}
```

The Java implementation creates a map of size 7523 and the C++ one is 7967. There are 45234 elements inspected total for both so it seems to be iterating correctly through the potential keys.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried overloading operators, custom comparators, custom hash functions, etc. and I must be missing something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to help avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to an unordered map, using a a custom hash function, and overloading the == operator did the trick

```
auto hashCode = [](const RVPoint3D pt)
{
    return pt.x + pt.y + pt.z;
};

std::unordered_map<RVPoint3D, int, std::function<double(RVPoint3D)>> pointMap{modelFull.getFaces().size(), hashCode};
```

I guess my initial attempt at this was incorrect somehow but this works perfectly so maybe it'll will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the `java` version for new map items you set `v` to `0` then add `1` to it when you put it in the map. \in the `C++` version you put it in as just `0`.

**Java**

```
Integer v = map.get(p);
if (v == null) {
    v = 0;
}
map.put(p, v + 1); // new map entries go in as 1
```

**C++**

```
if (pointMap.count(pt))
{
    pointMap[pt] += 1;
} else {
    pointMap[pt] = 0; // new map entries go in as 0
}
```

Also can you set a `null` `Iteger` to `0` in Java? Don't you need to do something like:

```
v = new Integer(0); // ?
```

**Side Note:**

The `C++` code can be rewritten as:

```
for (const auto &face : modelFaces)
{
    Face newFace(face); // Value, no need for Java-like syntax
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
    {
        RVPoint3D pt = newFace.getPts()[k];
        ++pointMap[pt]; // auto sets to 1 on new entry
    }
    faces.push_back(newFace);
}
```

This works because if a key does not exist in a `std::map` one is created automatically (with the corresponding value `0`) when you access it using `pointMap[pt]`. So you can just increment and new values will start at `1` just as in the `Java` code.

Comment: Good catch on the C++ loop. I originally had something similar but I forgot to change it back. Unfortunately, that may have fixed an issue with the values but it still doesn't fix the extra items in the map.
The Java code appears to be working fine so I'm not sure about setting the Integer to null. I have no control over that code and no documentation.

Comment: @rghamilton3 Then I would assume your problem is elsewhere. Maybe the source of your values? Are you feeding your maps exactly the same thing? It may be worth comparing *that* code to see of you are doing something different between `Java` and `C++`.

Comment: @rghamilton3 Is your `Point3D` class integer or floating point?

Comment: I thought I was but I'm revamping my tests to hopefully further ensure that I'm feeding them the same values.
The Point3D is floating point.

Comment: @rghamilton3 It is quite possible/likely your floating point values are not ***exactly*** the same between `Java` and `C++`. Small rounding differences with every calculation etc may make them very slightly different. This would affect key collisions. In fact I am not at all certain of the merit of using floating point keys tbh.

Comment: At this point I'm fairly certain it is related to that but may have something to do with how `Java` and `C++` compare keys. `Java` makes you override `==` but `C++` makes you override `<`. The `Java` considers equal to be the squared Euclidean distance < 1E-6. I'm not quite sure how to properly overload the `<` operator for `C++` to be equivalent. I'm with you on the floating point keys. My initial implementation is obviously wrong (embarrassingly wrong really) so I need to investigate further. Thanks for all your help. I do appreciate it.